# How to use publishProgress() method inside a function called from doInBackground()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress

I am using a function call from inside doInBackground() method in AsyncTask class 
How do I call it from function .

Kindly help .

I am using

```
// function name 
private void getFilteredHeaderData(FilterHeaderTask obj) {

    obj.onProgressUpdate("Updated Progress data ... ");


}
```

where FilterHeaderTask  is the AsyncTask class name

The app gets crashed after encountering the line of obj.onProgressUpdate();

My doInBackground() function from AsyncTask

```
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {   

            getFilteredHeaderData(this);


            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Check out this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: u can only call it from doInBackground

Comment: what is the need of passing obj to ur function..

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
obj.onProgressUpdate("Updated Progress data ... ");
```

with

```
publishProgress("Updated progress data .......");
```

**Updated :**

```
protected final void publishProgress(Progress... values){}
```

`publishProgress()` has the protected access so you cannot invoke from other classes.

Comment: publishProgress() works only if the progress is shown from inside the doInBackground() method ... I am calling another method from inside the doInBackground() method from which I need to update my progress

Comment: publishProgress() is used to update the UI thread from the doInBackground, so definitely it will works here.

Comment: onProgressUpdate should'nt be called directly, if you call it directly it run in the background thread, and may result in excetption while updating the UI.

Comment: Yes ... you are right ...but how can I update my progress from getFilteredHeaderData() which is in another function in another class

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution who is functional. 
I use pdialog.setProgress(x); directly in the called method.

The call of that method in doInBackground is in the format : 
int xx = class.method(some params..., pdialog); // where pdialog is the ProgressDialog created in the main thread (pdialog = new ProgressDialog(this);)